# How to declare table in returning clause as %TYPE of existing table?

Tags: postgresql

This is a part of a declaration of a function to move moneys from one account to another with fee. It have to return the full record of debitor. Now it is declared as returning the table and all the rows, like that:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SPACE(
      debit RECORD,
      credit RECORD,
      howmuch INTEGER,
      fee INTEGER )
  RETURNS TABLE(
    id BIGINT,
    client_id BIGINT,
    tag VARCHAR(128),
    amount INTEGER,
    currency VARCHAR(12),
    status purse_status,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone ) AS $BODY$
  BEGIN -- etc
```

**But**, I have really 4 overloaded functions, and I do not want to change all those declarations after changing the table 'purses'. The example below do not work, just a syntax error. So the question is: can I declare that return statement shortly with syntax like purses%TYPE or anything like that?

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SPACE(
      debit RECORD,
      credit RECORD,
      howmuch INTEGER,
      fee INTEGER )
    RETURNS purses%TYPE AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
      UPDATE purses
        SET amount = amount - howmuch - fee
        WHERE id = debit.id;

      UPDATE purses
        SET amount = amount + howmuch
        WHERE purses.id = credit.id;

      UPDATE purses
        SET amount = amount + fee
        WHERE client_id = 0 AND currency = credit.currency AND tag = 'space';

      RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM purses WHERE purses.id = debit.id;
      RETURN;
    END $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a setof a table type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SPACE(
      debit RECORD,
      credit RECORD,
      howmuch INTEGER,
      fee INTEGER )
  RETURNS setof purses
....
```